# How to access individual datepicker added into a html table

Tags: javascript, html

I managed to add datepicker into my table but how do i trigger individual "action". For example,if I choose datepicker on row 1, I want to add that date into my array object. if I choose datepicker on row 2, same thing.

I'm using class="datepicker" and

```
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

to enable the datepicker functionality

```
$.each(aItems, function(i, post) {

                let oQtyModal = "itemqtymodal_" + i;
                let oDate = "iDate_" + i;

                html2 += '<tr>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-MATNR"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-PRICE"] + '</td>';
                //html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>'  + '<input type="text"' + 'onchange="getQty(this)"' + 'name="' + oQtyModal + '"' + 'id="' + oQtyModal + '"' + 'value='+post["NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY"]+'>' + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td align="center">' + post["NEW_ITEM-UNIT"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + '<input type="text"' + 'class="datepicker"' + 'id="' + oDate + '"' + '/>' +'</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + '<input type="button" onClick="deleteProduct(this)" value="Delete Item" />' + '</td>';
                html2 += '</tr>';           
                $('#table2 tbody').html(html2);
                });
            jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker();
            }
```

Can anyone guide me on how I can add a date into my array object uniquely via the input id(so that we will know which row?)?

Comment: You can use HTML 5 input type date control

Comment: but I'm worried if user is using a lower version of IE.

Comment: You can tell them to use updated browser, thats all we do now actually no one west there time on date picker this day i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    $(document).on("focus", ".datepicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
```